# Lost recieved data when calling recv twice in C socket

Tags: c, sockets, embedded-linux

I'm trying to read the first 4 bytes received from network to get the whole message length then I get all the message like this:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
int len,length;
char *buffer, lengthX[4];
recv(com_handle, lengthX, 4, 0);
sscanf(lengthX, "%" S(4) "X", &len);
length=recv(com_handle, buffer , len, 0);
```

for some reasons I loose 13 bytes of the rest of the message.
Any Ideas?

Comment: You code is wrong and incomplete.  What is `msgLength`?

Comment: you're right I've modified it's "length" because I've copied it from big source code

Comment: Did you try to print the actual value of len received from network ? I cannot guess whether `"%d" S(4) "X"` is correct or not ...

Comment: Now there are two vars named 'length'.

Comment: You MUST handle correctly the value returned by recv(). Ignoring it is very, very bad.:(

Comment: There is too much guessing about your code. Is `buffer` the same variable as `char *buf`? If so, is it uninitialised in your original source code as well? How do you know there are bytes missing? Is `len` wrong? Is `length` wrong? Are both lengths correct but `buffer` doesn't hold what expected?

Comment: well for buf it's **buffer** just little mistake but in my code source it's correct, Ill change it right now. for the length is wrong I've got less than real size apparently it's related to special charter in the data that I've sent via network thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `recv()` function does not guarantee to read the full number of bytes specified.  Its Linux manual page describes it this way:

> The receive calls normally return any data available, up to the requested amount, rather than waiting for receipt of the full amount requested.

In this way it is like `read(2)`, which I prefer for most purposes.  The type of socket (stream vs. datagram) impacts this, but with either function, you may need to be prepared to loop, reading repeatedly in order to collect all the pieces of the message.

And *always* check the return value of your syscalls.  In this case, not only do you need to do so to detect errors, you need to do so to ensure that you read correctly at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return value of recv continuously to find out how many bytes you received with each recv call. The reason is that you are using a streaming protocol and you can receive any arbitrary amount of bytes at any time and not in the way you have sent them at the sender.

If you send 100 bytes and then immediately thereafter send 100 bytes again, chances are that you will receive 200 bytes but it might also be 150 and 50 or something else. Your logic should be written as such that the data stream might be chopped in many pieces of arbitrary size. So you need a loop of some kind that is calling receive all the time and fills some intermediate buffer. Only when you received 4 bytes you can know how many bytes are yet to come but you don't know how many recv calls that will take. Also if you send multiple of these kind of messages. Length followed with length bytes of data and then again length followed with data (2 messages). Be aware that you will receive this as a continuous stream so you might receive data of the previous packet together with the length of the next along with some bytes of that next message. You'll need quite some logic to cope with this because your 4 bytes of the length itself can be broken and spread over 2 recv calls or more.

Also check for receiving 0 bytes because that means that the peer has closed its end of the connection.

You should read a little more about network programming I always see the same mistakes here where people just don't get what a streaming protocol is. But this kind of information is available on the internet. First start reading, then comes understanding, then comes experimentation and coding followed by further understanding.